# Run-time error '1004' using a formula in a macro vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to insert a formula in a macro vba and write the output in a cell but i get a run-time error.. I'm not a vba developer so i can't understand what is wrong. I write only some simple macros.. This is what i wrote so far:

```
Sub count()

  Range("E6").Formula = "=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(MATCH(A2:A96;A2:A96;0);MATCH(A2:A96;A2:A96;0))>0;1))"

End Sub
```

I expect that in the `E6` cell will get the output, using only the formula i get 51, but when i run the macro i get the error.. Any help? Thanks

EDIT: Using InputBox

```
 Dim myRange As Range

    Set myRange = Application.InputBox(Prompt:= _
        "Select a Range", _
        Title:="InputBox Method", Type:=8)

    Range("E6").Formula = "=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(MATCH(A2:A96,A2:A96,0),MATCH(A2:A96,A2:A96,0))>0,1))"
```

Comment: replace `;` semicolon with `,` comma. Even if your default sep is `;`, in `VBA` it's `,`.

Answer (score 2):

You should us US style separators:

```
  Range("E6").Formula = "=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(MATCH(A2:A96,A2:A96,0),MATCH(A2:A96,A2:A96,0))>0,1))"
```

Answer (score 0):

As commented, this should work:

```
Range("E6").Formula = _
    "=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(MATCH(A2:A96,A2:A96,0),MATCH(A2:A96,A2:A96,0))>0,1))"
```

Comment: Well both answers, yours and @Roby answer goes well. Both works thank you. Is it possible make the range as variable by a dialog with edittext? i mean range: `A2:A96` of the two match.

Comment: Well, he also change `;` to `,` in his answer so it will work of course. Even normal formula can be entered as array formula. Try using his answer but use the `;`? Btw, Yes. Try `Application.InputBox`

Comment: Can you see my edit? i tried insert the InputBox for my range.. but i think than i have to insert the value in my Formula instead `A2:A96,A2:A96` right?